# Get log of the executed query when edit/delete data on the result set

Tags: datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I'm using DataGrip-2017.2.3 and unable to find the log/history of the executed query on the result data set

Answer (score 1):

If you need to see which particular query was run to get this result, click on gear icon and choose *View Query*.

[image]

Just for you to know about query logs:

1. In the *Output* tab there is a log of what you were running in this console. If you update data in the grid, the update queries will appear here as well.
2. On the toolbar of every console there is a small icon with a **clock**. It is a log of all queries to the data source.
3. *Help | Show SQL Log...* will lead you to the file where **all** queries from DataGrip are stored. But it works from 2018.2, so I advice you to use up-to-date version always.

Comment: I tried every solution that you provide moscas, but things didn't work for me. I think I need to go for the latest version as you said.

Comment: If you have questions better just drop a line to datagrip@jetbrains.com